# Is there any way to make the Android ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE tell the user why we need the folder selected?

Tags: android

Our application is a reader for ebooks, especially focused on early literacy materials for minority language speakers. One of the main ways our partners distribute ebooks is on SD cards. Therefore, our app needs permission to read a specific folder ("BloomExternal") on the SD card. In Android 11, we can only do this through SAF. Basically like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriOfBloomExternal);
```

and then we launch that intent and, if the user clicks the right buttons without first navigating somewhere else, the return value gives us the permission we need.

The problem is, the typical user of our application is a child just starting to learn to read who speaks no widely-spoken language and reads poorly. The user may not understand what a folder is, much less why she should need to tap 'use this folder' at this point. Even if a teacher is helping her, it may not be obvious what needs to be done.

So, it would be nice if there was some way to (at least) put our own explanation into the dialog...something like, "Please click the button below to give Bloom Reader permission to access the books on your SD card".

I thought from the documentation that we could do this with

```
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_PROMPT, ...message);
```

But doing so has no effect at all.

It would be better still if we could bypass the chooser and go straight to "Allow Bloom Reader to access files in BloomExternal" (the message that comes up after a click on "use this folder"). In this context, there is no reason for the user to choose some other folder. Again, it would be nice if we could at least try to explain why we need this permission, though many of our readers probably wouldn't understand the explanation as it's not feasible to localize it into a language they know, and they aren't fluent readers.

Our current less-than-satisfactory solution is to put up a dialog before launching the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent. It has a localizable explanation and a picture encouraging the user to tap the necessary button in the next screen. Now the user has to tap twice, and of course the appearance of the button may be different in the next OS version, making our dialog out-of-date.

Any better ideas would be welcome.

(It would also, of course, be *extremely* welcome if the makers of Android would provide some way to identify a folder as containing nothing confidential, so that such a folder may be read by any app that wants to without bothering the user. Then we could manufacture the SD cards with BloomExternal folders so marked and avoid confusing our users like this.)

Comment: intent.addFlags() has no effect. Remove it as it is confusing code. The putExtra for initial uri will not work if the directory is not choosen before. Please explain first how and if this works for you.

Comment: So does the gui open in your folder on de removable micro sd card? Hard to believe. That child first has to find the sd card before it can navigate to your folder.

Comment: "Then we could manufacture the SD cards with BloomExternal folders so marked and avoid confusing our users like this" -- what level of control do you have for those cards? Do the directories have to be named `BloomExternal/`? Your app has blanket access to `getExternalFilesDirs()` locations. I have not tried pre-creating such a directory on removable storage to see if an app can still access it, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: We managed to figure out a way to open the GUI on the right folder, at least on the test device I've been using. Rather kludgy way of figuring out what the content: URI would have to be for it. Not sure yet how well it will transfer to other devices.

Comment: We have pretty complete control over what gets put on the SD cards. Basically anything a desktop could write. We'd prefer to keep using BloomExternal so as not to change things, but a more complicated path would be OK. Unfortunately, our experiments indicate that there isn't one unique path to a directory that every installation of our app will see as its getExternalFilesDirs() location.